# Configure Search bar for modern page to menu bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-pages

[image]I would like to know if this can possible to do without Spfx, enable the search function or engine to menu bar in the modern page without framework. I know it can be possible with the customize but i need to know or suggestion to enable without code.

In the image, that search engine is possible to search only site pages "Search Site Pages". Similarly for .aspx page i am looking for "Search this Page"

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SharePoint-Online-Modern-search-on-pages-and-libraries/m-p/301370

Similar to the above post

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean the menu bar?

In the modern page, the search box is in the suite bar in the top of the page. It is by design.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, perhaps i was looking for search in menu bar where you will find "Edit" page function "Page Details" function i needed to add the search engine there. And not for site but for the current page.

Comment: I am afraid that we cannot the add the search engine in the menu bar.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the "Search this site" to "Search current page" using pnp powershell

Comment: I am afraid that we cannot change the "Search this site" to "Search current page", because the search results are from site, lists and libraries. If you search the content of one page, then it will return the page. So, we cannot search in current page.

Comment: More or less the same feature but instead of searching the entire site, i have all the webparts like lists, libraries etc on this page. My point was instead of searching this into the entire site i will search the same on "Search this page". But can this be an implementation in coming days ?